# ORA-06502 in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure, ora-06502

Hello I have this simple procedure that compiles fine but after I initialize the variables the error is this.

The table is created like this

```
Create table vcelar_pomocky 
(
    cislo_nakupu Number(5,0) NOT NULL ,
    cislo_ula Number(5,0) NOT NULL ,
    rodne_cislo Varchar2 (30) NOT NULL ,
    datum_nakupu Date NOT NULL ,
    nazov Varchar2 (20) NOT NULL ,
    typ_polozky Varchar2 (20) NOT NULL ,
    cena_polozky Number(5,2) NOT NULL ,

    primary key (cislo_nakupu) 
) 
/
```

The procedure looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE quera_pomocky
(
v_cislo_nakupu  IN  VCELAR_POMOCKY.cislo_nakupu%TYPE,
v_nazov         OUT VCELAR_POMOCKY.nazov%TYPE,
v_cena_polozky  OUT VCELAR_POMOCKY.cena_polozky%TYPE
)
IS
BEGIN
    SELECT  nazov || ' ' || typ_polozky,cena_polozky
        INTO v_nazov,v_cena_polozky
        FROM VCELAR_POMOCKY
        WHERE v_cislo_nakupu = cislo_nakupu AND rodne_cislo = '750927/3913';
END quera_pomocky;
/

VARIABLE p_nazov VARCHAR2(20);
VARIABLE p_cena_polozky VARCHAR2(20);
EXECUTE quera_pomocky(24, :p_nazov , :p_cena_polozky);
PRINT p_nazov p_cena_polozky;
```

And the error is

> Error starting at line : 65 in command -
>   BEGIN quera_pomocky(24, :p_nazov , :p_cena_polozky); END;
>
> Error report:
>
> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
>   ORA-06512: at "DOMA.QUERA_POMOCKY", line 9
>   ORA-06512: at line 1
>   06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
>   *Cause: An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>   declared NUMBER(2).
>
> *Action: Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so that values do not violate constraints.

Comment: Please edit your answer and show us the definition ot the table VCELAR_POMOCKY. We need the datatypes, which are used by the `%TYPE` construct in your query...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting this:

```
nazov || ' ' || typ_polozky
```

into a parameter

```
v_nazov OUT VCELAR_POMOCKY.nazov%TYPE
```

which is - in a table - declared as

```
nazov Varchar2 (20)
```

So: if length of `nazov || ' ' || typ_polozky` exceeds `20` characters (mind you: both are - in the table - declared as `varchar2(20)` which makes that concatenation's `MAX` length `41`), you're in trouble.

I'd suggest you to set `OUT` parameter to e.g.

```
v_nazov OUT varchar2(50)
```